# Embedded iframe URL to include current user id in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, variables, iframe

I have embedded the following URL on my wordpress page as an iframe with the following code:

```
<iframe src="https://cpalead.com/mobile/locker/?pub=195930&gateid=985632&subid=$user" height="100%" frameborder="0" name="iframetarget" id="iframetarget"></iframe>
```

my page template has define the $user parameter as follows:

`$user = get_current_user_id();`

however, when my page loads the iframe the URL source is this:

```
https://cpalead.com/mobile/locker/?pub=195930&gateid=985632&subid=$user
```

It does not pass the $user variable to the iframe source URL....like so, say user 1 is logged in, the source URL should be:

```
https://cpalead.com/mobile/locker/?pub=195930&gateid=985632&subid=1
```

I have debugged this with a bit of php:

`echo "you are user $user";`

which does display the correct user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: plese try this : https://cpalead.com/mobile/locker/?pub=195930&gateid=985632&subid=<?php echo $user; ?>

Comment: What does `var_dump($user)` say? When you ask a question about an error, ***ALWAYS***, post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is the url not correctly formatted or is the userid in the url but not available in the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it as text. You should `echo` the value of the variable

```
<iframe src="https://cpalead.com/mobile/locker/?pub=195930&gateid=985632&subid=<?php echo $user; ?>" height="100%" frameborder="0" name="iframetarget" id="iframetarget"></iframe>
```

then inside the `iframe` you can use
`$_GET['subid']` to use the value

Comment: I'm doing this but the link source is now this:  https://cpalead.com/mobile/locker/?pub=195930&gateid=985632&subid=<?php echo $user; ?> the php isn't being compiled......darn, i'm using visual composer with wordpress

Comment: is your code in a .php file? Show more of your code

Comment: Had to create a new page template for wordpress, for more control over my iframe. It understood the echo$user and worked, thanks guys!